# Check the value of image is valid? or not?

Tags: java, android, performance, web-services

I am new to android.i saved image value in database.but i have to check that value.so How can check the value of image in database is correct or not

Comment: what do you mean by value of a image??\

Comment: i stored byte[] value in database.i have to check it out

Comment: So you want to check if it's a valid image? Don't you perhaps want to do that before you save the data, then just assume the database can correctly store and retrieve this for you?

Comment: okay. last question, Database means local mobile or remote server database

Comment: #Duncan I didn't get you

Comment: #MDMalik remote server database

Comment: @user3543997 Use the '@' symbol to reply to people. My question was about why you want to do this. Are you worried that the database didn't store the value correctly, or that it was modified after you stored it? Or is this data you've received from elsewhere and you need to check that it's a valid image?

Comment: @Duncan i saved image in database.i can't see the image when i retrive that image from database.so oly